# How do you iterate through current class properties (not inherited from a parent or abstract class)?

Tags: php, class, properties, iteration

I know that PHP5 will let you iterate through a class's properties.  However, if the class extends another class, then it will include all of those properties declared in the parent class as well.  That's fine and all, no complaints.

However, I always understood SELF as a pointer to the current class, while $this also points to the current object (including stuff inherited from a parent)

Is there any way I can iterate ONLY through the current class's properties.  Reason why I'm asking this.... I'm using CI and iterating through $this includes tons of parent properties that I don't need.

```
<?php

class parent 
{
   public $s_parent = "Parent sez hi!";
   public $i_lucky_number = 6;
}

class child extends parent
{
   public $s_child = "Child sez hi!";
   public $s_foobar = "What What!!";
   public $i_lucky_number = 7;

   public iterate()
   {
      foreach ($this as $s_key => $m_val)
      {
          echo "$s_key => $m_val<br />\n";
      }
   }

}

$o_child = new child();
$o_child->iterate()
```

The output is

```
s_parent => Parent sez hi! 
s_child => Child sez hi! 
s_foobar => What What!!
i_lucky_number => 7
```

I DON'T Want to see "s_parent => Parent sez hi!"

I just want to iterate through the current class's properties.  Not those inherited elsewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `private $variable` in parent class ??!!

Comment: IMHO, cleaner answer in comment by Jessica on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215471/199364).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the Reflection methods, you could do the following:

```
public function iterate()
{
  $refclass = new ReflectionClass($this);
  foreach ($refclass->getProperties() as $property)
  {
    $name = $property->name;
    if ($property->class == $refclass->name)
      echo "{$property->name} => {$this->$name}\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. Haven't had time to test it yet.  I will get back to you.