# Retrieving only properties of the child class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties

I have a class like

```
class parent{
   public $foo;
}

class child extends parent{
   public $lol;

    public function getFields()
    {
        return array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__));
    }
}
```

and I get a array with the child properties in it to...

```
array('foo','lol');
```

is there a simple solution to get only the properties from the child class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach (may contain pseudo PHP code :))

```
class parent{
   public $foo;

   public function getParentFields(){
        return array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__));
   }
}

class child extends parent{
   public $lol;

    public function getFields()
    {   
        $parentFields = parent::getParentFields();
        $myfields = array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__));

        // just subtract parentFields from MyFields and you get the properties only exists on child

        return the diff
    }
}
```

The idea that using parent::getParentFields() function to determine which fields was parent fields.

Comment: I started working on the same thing, +1. May need to add recursion. You can also skip the parent function and just use `get_class_vars()` directly on `get_parent_class()` OP: use `array_diff` to get the child-fields

Comment: Or, get_class_vars(parent) might just work :), I am too lazy to try it :)

Comment: @KemalDağ `get_class_vars(parent)` doesn't work because PHP considers it as a string literal `'parent'` when you pass it to a function.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija Thank you very much, the lesson well learned by a lazy programmer :)

Answer (score 6):

as posted in the link to [How do you iterate through current class properties (not inherited from a parent or abstract class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902406/how-do-you-iterate-through-current-class-properties-not-inherited-from-a-parent)

```
public function iterate()
{
  $refclass = new ReflectionClass($this);
  foreach ($refclass->getProperties() as $property)
  {
    $name = $property->name;
    if ($property->class == $refclass->name)
      echo "{$property->name} => {$this->$name}\n";
  }
}
```

It is GREAT solution up voted and favorited! thy!!! who ever linked to this one!