# How to get public class properties (not inherited ones)

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way to get only the public classes properties in the Mailable class (not the inherited ones), for example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestMail1 extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $name; // i want to get only this

    public $body; // and this

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */ 
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.simpleview')->subject('New Mail');
    }
}
```

This class (TestMail1) inherits many properties from the extended class (Mailable), but i want only to get the `name` and `body` properties defained in the class itself

i try this:

```
$mailable = (new mailable1);

$data = new ReflectionClass($mailable);

$properties = $data->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);

$properties_in = [];

foreach ($properties as $prop) {
    if ($prop->class == $data->getName())
     $properties_in[] = $prop->name;
}

dd($properties_in);
```

but this returns:

```
array:8 [▼
      0 => "name"
      1 => "body"
      2 => "connection"
      3 => "queue"
      4 => "chainConnection"
      5 => "chainQueue"
      6 => "delay"
      7 => "chained"
    ]
```

Any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you iterate through current class properties (not inherited from a parent or abstract class)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902406/how-do-you-iterate-through-current-class-properties-not-inherited-from-a-parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties showing up are not *inherited*, they are *included from a Trait*.

You can see the difference if you look at a simpler example:

```
trait T {
    public $pasted;
}

class A {
    public $foo;
}

class B extends A {
    use T;

    public $bar;
}

$data = new ReflectionClass(B::class);
$properties = $data->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
$properties_in = [];
foreach ($properties as $prop) {
    if ($prop->class == $data->getName()) {
        $properties_in[] = $prop->name;
    }
}
print_r($properties_in);
```

This shows `$bar` from class `B` and `$pasted` from trait `T`, but not `$foo` from  class `A`.

In the same way, your output is not showing you fields from class `Mailable` but from the two traits imported by the statement `use Queueable, SerializesModels;`

This is acting as designed: a trait is considered "compile-time copy-and-paste", so the members included from the trait are indistinguishable from those defined directly in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
$extended = new ReflectionClass('\App\Mail\TestMail1');
$base     = new ReflectionClass('\App\Mail\Mailable');

$properties_in = array_diff(
    $extended->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC),
    $base->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC)
);

dd($properties_in);
```

Comment: I think this will give the same result - the extra properties showing up *aren't* in `Mailable`, they're in the `Queueable` and `SerializesModels` traits. However, you might be able to use a similar approach to reflect the traits themselves and `array_diff` against those.